# how to do ajaxSetup beforeSend like stuff in DOJO toolkit to provide CSRF token in DOJO AJAX POSTs

Tags: ajax, django, dojo, csrf

Recent releases of Django require csrf_token to be sent along with each POST request (whether through AJAX or through normal request).

[Flaw in CSRF handling fixed.](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/feb/08/security/)

They suggest that, Django will now accept the CSRF token in the custom HTTP header X-CSRFTOKEN, as well as in the form submission itself, for ease of use with popular JavaScript toolkits which allow insertion of custom headers into all AJAX requests.

They give an example to do this in jQuery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
                                 $("#csrfmiddlewaretoken").val());
        }
    }
});
```

I am not able to figure out how to do something similar in DOJO toolkit.
I have been using dojo.rpc.JsonService() for a while.

Please suggest a way to do something similar in DOJO?

Or the only option is to do this on each and every xhrPost request separately?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with django.

Outside of extending the base dojo xhr definition(wouldn't recommend it), I'd say you may want to extend dojo.xhr or build a utility method.

Utility method would mix in or set the "headers" attribute of the arguments you pass into dojo.xhr :

myCustomNameSpace.xhr = function (xhrArgs) {
  var csrfHeader = { "X-CSRFToken" : dojo.byId(csrfmiddlewaretoken).val(); }; 
  xhrArgs.headers?dojo.mixin(xhrArgs.headers,csrfHeader):xhrArgs.headers=csrfHeader;
  dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
};

Invoked via myCustomNameSpace.xhr({method:"POST",url:"http://www....."});

Answer (score 1):

The {% csrf_token %} will appear in the form just like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='...' />
```

so just mix your content like this:

```
var form = dojo.byId("postForm");
dojo.xhrPost({url:form.action,
    content:{text:form.text.value, csrfmiddlewaretoken:form.csrfmiddlewaretoken.value},
)
```